# How to override Flux color temperature settings in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, f.lux

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. [Flux](https://justgetflux.com/) runs fine during night time. But I would like to reduce the color temperature of the screen during daytime too to reduce the strain on my eyes.

However Flux indicator applet does not allow to manually set the color temperature in day time. It changes the color gradually over the day depending on your coordinates. Please see the image.

[image]

Is there a workaround to this problem? How do I set the color temperature to a constant 2800K at all times?